# Deploying WebParts and Extensions in SPFx

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, spfx

We have a solution with an app extender (mega menu and some look n feel jquery teicks) and a web part.

We are trying to deploy it.  It's pretty easy getting the dev version in the App Catalog and running it with local scripts.  The extender doesn't seem to show up l, however the web part is working.

We want to know if we can deploy a shipping or production version without deploying Scripts to an o365 CDN. This part is not clear since we thought we could just package all and throw it into the App Catalog...

Any guidelines if we don't want to use the CDN?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use CDN, as a workaround, we can create SharePoint Library as CDN.

1.Create a document library(named "SPFxDeploy") in your SharePoint Site, and give read permission to all users.

2.Configure SPFx Solution for SharePoint Library, open package-solution.json file from config folder and set includeClientSideAssets value as false.

3.Update CDN Path, open write-manifests.json file from config folder and update CDN base path as SharePoint library URL.

4.Prepare the package using "gulp bundle --ship", then upload the files from "temp\deploy" folder to SharePoint library.

5.Upload package to the app catalog.

**Reference**: [SharePoint Framework - Deploy SPFx WebParts to SharePoint Library](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/sharepoint-framework-deploy-spfx-webparts-to-sharepoint-library/)